# api woocommerce não conecta

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

bom dia a todos!! 
Pessoal, instalei o woocommerce em localhost e quero estudar a api dele...fui lá, gerei as chaves e estou chamando a api assim:

```
http://localhost/boramonstro/wp-json/wc/v2/orders?consumer_key=ck_ec1551961e3be01c1279c351413be8c88b35d8ad&consumer_secret=cs_125f7e0e142b122f24d476e5666cccf1b2b8000e
```

e o retorno é

```
{"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"Sorry, you cannot list resources.","data":{"status":401}}
```

o que eu posso ter feito de errado??? pode ser versão??
alguém me de uma luz!! acredito ter feito tudo certo, mas não funciona!!
Obrigado a todos!! 
bom dia!

Answer (score 0):

Use o modo de login como: OAuth 1.0

No localhost você não tem o SSL com isso não é possível usar a versão V2.

Exemplo da versão V1: https://website.tld/wp-json/wc/v1/products?consumer_key=[key]&consumer_secret=[secret]